# malloc double datatype with strlen

Tags: c

how do I allocate memory for `strlen(esc)` in a proper way? The `temp` and `str` are char datatypes.

```
double esc = t1.tv_sec+(t1.tv_usec/1000000.0);
strAll = malloc(strlen(temp) + strlen(str) + strlen(esc) + 1);
```

Comment: `esc` isn't a string. What are you hoping `strlen(esc)` will return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot take `strlen(esc)`. As I am sure the compiler has already told you, the argument to `strlen()` must be `char *`, you are passing it a `double`. Try first converting the `double` to array of `char` with `snprintf()`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to convert `esc` to a string, probably with `sprintf()`.  Then use the length from that in the `malloc()`:

```
char buffer[32];
int  n = snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%.6f", esc);
if (n >= sizeof(buffer))
    ...handle overlong string problems (bail out)...
char *strAll = malloc(strlen(temp) + strlen(str) + n + 1);
if (strAll == 0)
    ...handle out of memory problem (bail out)...
sprintf(strAll, "%s%s%s", temp, str, buffer);
```

(I didn't check the length returned by `sprintf()` because 'it cannot go wrong'.  You calculated the length of the component strings, and therefore, it will fill exactly the allocated space.  If you do decide to check it, then preserve the length that is the argument to `malloc()` and test against that.)

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:1999 §7.19.6.5 'The `snprintf` function' says: _The `snprintf` function returns the number of characters that would have been written
had `n` been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative
value if an encoding error occurred. Thus, the null-terminated output has been
completely written if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than `n`._  The output is null terminated; it may be incomplete and `snprintf()` tells you how big the buffer should have been for it to be successful.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the length you need using snprintf. Passing '0' as the size will prevent is from writing any bytes, and it returns the number of bytes it would have needed.

```
size_t length = snprintf(0, 0, "%lf%s%lf", esc, temp, esc) + 1;
strAll = malloc(length);
snprintf(strAll, length, "%lf%s%lf", esc, temp, esc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code don't compile. `strlen` expects a string argument, that is a pointer to a sequence of `char` (like an array).

Perhaps you want something like

```
char buf[30];
double esc = somedoublefunction();
snprintf (buf, sizeof(buf), "%f", esc);
return strdup(buf);
```

of course you should care to later `free` the resulting pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of the following if you're just trying to save all the data in one buffer:

sizeof(esc) or sizeof(double)

If you want to turn esc into a string. Otherwise, I would suggest using a fixed point format when converting to a string e.g. snprintf(buffer, 7, "%03.3f", esc);

Comment: I don't think it is helpful. The poster apparently is confused by C and probably wants to build a dynamically allocated string containing some decimal representation of some floating pointer.

Comment: Those would give the size in bytes of the variable, but the intent is presumably to create a string from 3 parts, one of which needs to be a string representation of `esc`.  So this doesn't really help, does it?

Comment: would it be idea to use variable with fixed size like vara[30], is there any performance benefit?